get yourself set up
On TV, someone is warning how to avoid scammers in buying concert tickets. She says:
"....but for this weekend get yourself set up, only buy from the registered official sites, and do not get tempted to buy any resaletickets on the rebound on social media. ITV-concert tickets - dodge the scams (see: 6:58-7:09)
What does it mean "....get yourself set up"? Does it mean "be alert, be careful"?

Maybe 'do some preparatory work first' also. Research scams, make plenty of time available so you don't rush things and make a careless mistake.

Don't worry too much about learning from casual spoken settings like this. Much of what is said doesn't set out patterns to follow, but rather makes sense only in this particular conversation, or not even there.

@AndyBonner get yourself cleaned up; get yoursef up, get yourself home  and loads more.

In general, "get yourself set up" just means make some suitable preparations for what you are about to do.
It may mean do your research into what performers are guaranteed to be there, what seats are available, at what price and can I afford it.
It may mean to make sure you are going to the official web site and not some scam version.
Or if you decide to watch it at home on TV, make sure you've got enough cold beer and snacks on hand.
In a different context it can mean that you have found and rented a suitable premises, obtained stock and have now got yourself set up to .
open a business.
The phrase has wide application.

A nitpick: it should be "get yourself set up", not "get yourself setup".  Setup is a noun, set up is a verb.

@stangdon - agreed.

@MichaelHarvey & stangdon I also agree and have edited my answer to reflect this.

Yes, but it can be generalized to other expressions.
